# How to get the LogonName in ASP.NET without disabling Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I would like to be able to obtain the **Windows LogonName** of a user, without having to disable the Forms Authentication. I know that this could be possible by using the following line of code and by denying Anonymous Login in the .config file plus enabling Windows Authentication:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Is this something possible to achieve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible.  Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication are mutually exclusive. You can enable one or the other and the current user identity will be populated by the corresponding HTTP module.

Comment: So this isn't entirely true. Yes, if you wanted the authentication to be handled with some built-in code, they are exclusive. However, they are not *mutually exclusive* for any technical reason. The forms authentication could be handled manually, quite easily.

Comment: "Forms Authentication" in ASP.NET is a very specific technical  implementation - HTTP module provided by Microsoft and enabled in the application web.config.  It is mutually exclusive with Windows authentication enabled by the same web.config setting. The method you are describing in your answer (through session variable) is not forms authentication.  It is not a recommended solution for authentication from the security perspective, as the session cookie does not have the same safeguards as the forms authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this and yet still require forms authentication. You'll just have to determine "authenticated" on your own via a session variable or something. Just perform the steps you already stated and it will perform Windows authentication by default.

---

If you wanted to still require forms authentication, you'd need a flag in your `Session` to *know* the user was or wasn't authenticated. So, in the login process you might do this:

```
Session["IsAuthenticated"] = true;
```

Further, when the main page loaded, you might do this:

```
if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsAuthenticated"]))
{
    // redirect to the login page
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more on determining 'authenticated via a session variable? How do I do that exactly, thanks. @Michael Perrenoud

Answer (score 0):

If they are authenticated you should be able to use the following:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

OR

```
Page.User.Identity.Name;
```